# Update Table Column off of Query Column

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to Update a column in my table Inputcounts called concatenate off of a query called InputConcatenates that has a column also called concatenate. I am running an update query with the  field name as concatenate the table name as InputCounts and the update to field as [InputConcatenates].[Concatenate]. But every time I run the query it pulls back that 0 records will be updated. Is my syntax wrong possibly?

Update Query SQL:

```sql
UPDATE InputCounts INNER JOIN InputConcatenate
ON InputCounts.CONCATENATE = InputConcatenate.CONCATENATE 
SET InputCounts.CONCATENATE = [InputConcatenate].[CONCATENATE];
```

InputConcatenate Query SQL:

```sql
SELECT InputCounts.FLEET, InputCounts.AMMs, [FLEET] & [AMMs] AS CONCATENATE
FROM InputCounts;
```

Comment: Ok I have added the SQL for both queries

Comment: When you test this as a new query in the Access query designer, how many rows does it return?  `SELECT * FROM InputCounts INNER JOIN InputConcatenate ON InputCounts.CONCATENATE = InputConcatenate.CONCATENATE`

Comment: Its giving me a syntax error in JOIN operation

Comment: But that is the same join used in the `UPDATE` ... where you did not get a syntax error.  Right?

Comment: Oh crap I put an extra bracket... I'm sorry its outputing 10093 rows but there are duplicate columns

Comment: Good!  Now in each of those rows, the value in the `InputCounts.CONCATENATE` column matches the value in the `InputConcatenate.CONCATENATE` column of that row.  Correct?

Comment: Excellent!  Now what is the point of `SET InputCounts.CONCATENATE = [InputConcatenate].[CONCATENATE]`?  (You just confirmed those values are already equal.)  In the question you asked about a syntax error; the problem is a logic error.  Make sense?

Comment: Well when I add new rows to the table I will need the concatenate put back every and there is no way to have a calculate field that automatically run when a new row is added so I was trying to come up with a query that I can run when I add alot of new data to update that column

Comment: Still not sure I understand, but is this what you want? `UPDATE InputCounts SET CONCATENATE = [FLEET] & [AMMs] WHERE CONCATENATE Is Null;`

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to get to... so I just need one query now right just the update one with the SQL you just wrote?

Comment: Yeah it looks like it does. If it updates the concatenate column in the table when there is no concatenate then it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reported this query accomplishes what you want ...

```sql
UPDATE InputCounts
SET CONCATENATE = [FLEET] & [AMMs]
WHERE CONCATENATE Is Null;
```

That may be fine.  However `CONCATENATE` is not updated until you execute the `UPDATE`, and does not get updated (after having previously received a value) in response to changes in `FLEET` or `AMMs`

Decide whether `CONCATENATE` really needs to exist as a field in your table.  You could use a query to derive it whenever you need it:

```sql
SELECT *, FLEET] & [AMMs] AS CONCATENATE
FROM InputCounts;
```

With the query, `CONCATENATE` will always be up to date.

If your database is ACCDB format and your Access version is >= 2010, another possibility is to make `CONCATENATE` a "calculated field" type in the table's design:

[image: table Design View showing calculated field type]

If you prefer `CONCATENATE` be Null whenever FLEET or AMMs is Null, change the field's *Expression* property to `[FLEET] + [AMMs]`

The advantage of a calculated field is that Access automagically updates its value without further effort (like executing an `UPDATE`) from you.

A disadvantage is that you can't index a calculated field.  That means it's not suited for joins, `WHERE` criteria, `ORDER BY`, etc.  You'll have to decide whether it's a reasonable fit for your application.  :-)

Comment: OH my gosh thats so much better I kept trying to do that but with the equal sign in front and it kept saying no ma'am lol but when you mean it cant index does that mean I cant use it as a primary key?

Comment: Right ... a primary key is implemented as a unique index ... no index possible on calculated field ... so calulated field can not be a primary key.  But perhaps you could use a composite primary key based on `FLEET` and `AMMs`

Comment: How do I make a composite primary key?

Comment: Open table in Design View.  Click in the box on the left of `FLEET` to select that field.  Shift-click next to `AMMs` ... so you should have both those field selected.  Click Primary Key icon on the ribbon.